# PHP - passing arguments from an array to an SQL query

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I have an SQL query, where I would like to pass different parameters based on different scenarios. I am not sure how to do achieve this. This is the query:

```
$data = Engagement::leftJoin('user_engagement', 'engagements.id', '=', 'user_engagement.engagement_id')
            ->select('engagement_id', 'engagements.question', 'engagements.id')
            ->selectRaw('count(*) as count')
            ->whereBetween('user_engagement.created_at', [$from.' 00:00:00', $to.' 00:00:00'])
            ->groupBy('user_engagement.engagement_id')
            ->orderBy('count', 'DESC')
            ->take(5)
            ->get()->toArray();
```

So, what I would like to do this, would look something like this:

```
            $model = new Engagement;
            $leftJoin = ['user_engagement', 'engagements.id', '=', 'user_engagement.engagement_id'];
            $select = ['engagement_id', 'engagements.question', 'engagements.id'];
            $whereBetween = 'user_engagement.created_at';
            $groupBy = 'user_engagement.engagement_id';

            $data = $model->leftJoin($leftJoin)
            ->select($select)
            ->selectRaw('count(*) as count')
            ->whereBetween($whereBetween, [$from.' 00:00:00', $to.' 00:00:00'])
            ->groupBy($groupBy)
            ->orderBy('count', 'DESC')
            ->take(5)
            ->get()->toArray();
```

Comment: I think you can play with [call_user_func_array](http://php.net/manual/en/function.call-user-func-array.php) on the $model object and do the trick

Comment: take care about sql injection..

Comment: I can't use that on the model object I get ```Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::call_user_func_array()
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems like both `leftJoin` and `select` methods take several parameters instead of one array of parameters. This fix should work, but it's **not recommended**:

```
$leftJoin = [
  'user_engagement',
  'engagements.id',
  '=',
  'user_engagement.engagement_id'
];
$select = [
 'engagement_id',
 'engagements.question',
 'engagements.id'
];

…

data = $model->leftJoin($leftJoin[0], $leftJoin[1], $leftJoin[2], $leftJoin[3])
 ->select($select[0], $select[1], $select[2])
…
```

I would advise splitting your array into separate variables or creating an object for this purpose.

---

You can also go with more advanced way of using **[ReflectionMethod::invokeArgs](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/reflectionmethod.invokeargs.php)**

My guess is that it will look **something like** this:

```
$model = new Engagement;
$leftJoin = ['user_engagement', 'engagements.id', '=', 'user_engagement.engagement_id'];
$select = ['engagement_id', 'engagements.question', 'engagements.id'];
$whereBetween = 'user_engagement.created_at';
$groupBy = 'user_engagement.engagement_id';

$reflectLeftJoin = new ReflectionMethod('Engagement', 'leftJoin');
$reflectSelect = new ReflectionMethod('Engagement', 'select');

$reflectSelect->invokeArgs($model, $reflectLeftJoin->invokeArgs($model, $leftJoin))
  ->selectRaw('count(*) as count')
  ->whereBetween($whereBetween, [$from.' 00:00:00', $to.' 00:00:00'])
  ->groupBy($groupBy)
  ->orderBy('count', 'DESC')
  ->take(5)
  ->get()->toArray();
```

It's **NOT TESTED**.

Comment: The problem with this solution is that I would have the pass the array with same number of argument, and in my case the arrays will be of different size.

Comment: It doesn't work unfortunately, I get ```Class Engagement does not exist```

Comment: @Marco Maybe `array_replace` your parameters into `[null, null, …]` to get an array of required size.